# Double Linked List Node with two values

Tags: c++, linked-list

So if I had a double linked list and I wanted to add a name and also an age, so that I could search both separately how would i do it?

Comment: Just Do It. Put whatever data you need in the list nodes.

Comment: but would that still allow me to search based off of only age afterward?

Comment: You're the one writing the search code. It can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked lists are well suited to sorting in multiple keys:

```
 item0:   age=1             item1:    age=99;
          name='z'                    name='a';
          next_age=item1              next_age=NULL;
          next_name=NULL              next_name=item0
```

Basically the only extra thing to consider is how to arrange the list traversing algorithm to be shared and to be ignorant about location of the next/prev links.

One solution is to wrap the list structures to:

```
 struct list_s {
        struct list_s *next;
        struct list_s *prev;
        void *key_ptr;
        struct master_struct_s *parent;
 }

 struct master_struct_s {
        struct list_s key1;
        struct list_s key2;
        struct list_s key3;
        int other_data;
 }
```

Now a list sorting algorithm can work with &key1, &key2 or &key3 and possibly refer to the contents of other_data, as each list struct refers to the "parent" struct or their own container.

Answer (score 0):

You ask,

> “So if I had a double linked list and I wanted to add a name and also an age, so that I could search both separately how would i do it?”

As a practical matter you wouldn’t implement a doubly linked list for such a purpose. Instead you would use a standard library container such as `std::vector`. Or `std::map`.

But given that this is for learning, the question is what the question is…

I *think* you’re asking, how can you have each node participate in two linked lists at the same time.

And one easy way to do that is to have list nodes just contain pointers to the data nodes. As the saying goes, the solution to any computer science problem, is one extra layer of indirection. Of course that's also the solution to the problem of too much indirection. :-p